Android Cuttilefish not launch with building aosp
I build Debian packages and install, https://github.com/google/android-cuttlefish.
But Android Cuttilefish not work after build aosp aosp_cf_x86_auto, it shows error:

Detected unexpected exit of monitored subprocess
/media/workspace/zwd/workspace/aosp13/out/host/linux-x86/bin/crosvm
Subprocess /media/workspace/zwd/workspace/aosp13/out/host/linux-x86/bin/crosvm
(284511) has exited with exit code 0
Detected unexpected exit of monitored subprocess /media/workspace/zwd/workspace/aosp13/out/host/linux-x86/bin/crosvm
Subprocess /media/workspace/zwd/workspace/aosp13/out/host/linux-x86/bin/crosvm
(284582) has exited with exit code 0
GUEST_UBOOT_VERSION: 2022.01-15068-g240b124907 (Apr 14 2022 - 14:14:27 +0000)
U-Boot 20
[ERROR:external/crosvm/src/linux/mod.rs:1878] child xhci controller (pid 284623) died: signo 17, status 31, code 3
[ERROR:external/crosvm/devices/src/proxy.rs:227] failed write to child device process xhci controller: failed to send packet: Broken
pipe (os error 32)
[ERROR:external/crosvm/devices/src/proxy.rs:239] failed to read result of Shutdown from child device process xhci controller: tube was
disconnected
[ERROR:external/crosvm/devices/src/proxy.rs:239] failed to read result of ReadConfig(0) from child device process xhci controller:
failed to receive packet: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)
[ERROR:external/crosvm/src/linux/mod.rs:1878] child xhci controller (pid 284656) died: signo 17, status 31, code 3
[ERROR:external/crosvm/devices/src/proxy.rs:227] failed write to child device process xhci controller: failed to send packet: Broken
pipe (os error 32)
[ERROR:external/crosvm/devices/src/proxy.rs:239] failed to read result of Shutdown from child device process xhci controller: tube was
disconnected
Client closed the connection
Client closed the connection
Client closed the connection

